# CPU usage issue in queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

### **I have Linux Starter Plan on godaddy**

Below is the method in Kernel.php file.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:listen')->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

I have shared hosting account in Godaddy and using cron job for the Laravel Queue. I can't use Supervisor Queue because they don't allow SSH root access for my plan. Below is the screenshot. I am concerned about the CPU usage and Number of process.

[image]

My code uses queue for sending email for registration. That's it. No other thing is using Queue. Cron job is running after each 30 minutes for php artisan command. After running first time.it shows above stats.

Am I doing anything wrong?

### Then after 4-5 hours, it consumes 100% CPU

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong. You should **never** call `queue:listen` via the cron scheduler, otherwise you'll get unexpected behavior like what occurred to you. In this case, it sounds like you are spawning multiple queue listeners.

You should configure the `queue:listen` to run as a daemon process forever. If you dont have access to supervisor via GoDaddy, switch to a real server provider, like DigitalOcean or Linode - and use that.

Comment: There is no "correct code". The correct answer is switch server providers to someone who will give you what you need. GoDaddy is sh*t - just use DigitalOcean or Linode and you can do everything you need to do.

Comment: where can i check their prices and server configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I placed this gist a while back (look at the fork info to see the original works) to solve this same problem. It doesn't need much, apart being able to run exec() and also cares for periodic queue restart which it was needed for the specific project, but really not a general need.

https://gist.github.com/muihlinn/bcb17fc0b6425bcb6f26ac907bc91c10

**Note:** For some reason artisan's queue:restart command doesn't restart the queue, just kills it, hence both calls in the code.

Answer (score 2):

As Laurence has written queue:listen must not be started every 5 minutes as it keeps running it the background forever.

Try this gist, it might help solving your problem without switching hosting provider:

https://gist.github.com/sea-reel/3550cfe44c15d8f8878b34adf5814b15
(Laravel 5 Artisan Process Entire Queue and Exit Command)

So after adding the command in the gist, your schedule should look like:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('work-and-exit')->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you run shell commands from PHP? If so try this code in your App/Console/kernel.php

```
if (!strstr(shell_exec('ps xf'), 'php artisan queue:work'))
    {
        $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyFiveMinutes();
    }
```

I've struggled with the same and came up with this solution on my (A2hosting) shared hosting plan. It assures the queue is working and only one instance of it at all times. If you serialize `->emailWrittenOutputTo('your@email.com')` you get to know how often the command has to be restarted.

After one week of implementation, it works flawless. I run the `schedule:run` cron job every minute. In your case you can run it every 5 minutes.

**Addition**: your server stats are perfectly normal. At least 3 of the processes are actually cPanel (or similar) created processes. Run 'ps xf' in your shell and see for yourself.

**Last** but not least: you never, ever, have to run the `php artisan queue:work` command anymore. The cron job will take care of that. Even after a composer update.

Comment: This is not working at all still it goes to 100% CPU in 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [queue:restart](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment) command from time to time (for example every 5 minutes) to delete duplicated processes.

```
$schedule->command('queue:restart')->everyFiveMinutes();
$schedule->command('queue:work --daemon')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```